Can I create a loop to run a series of functions over multiple dataframes, but where the names need to be slightly adjusted each time?
I am working on a project to compile information from hundreds of email campaigns into one dataset. The platform we use makes us export the data for each action into separate CSVs, and there are three actions we are interested in, meaning we have three CSVs for each campaign. Here's an example with the naming convention:
Campaign_1_Delivered
Campaign_1_Opened
Campaign_1_Clicked

(If using a different naming convention helps with the solution, I can definitely rename)
There will eventually be hundreds of campaigns, and I've kept the naming convention going, just increasing the number by one for the next campaign (e.g., Campaign_2_Delivered, Campaign_3_Delivered, and so on to, currently, Campaign_112_Delivered). All CSV files have the same six columns, regardless of which data type they are:
Member ID, Email Address, First Name, Last Name, Activity, Date
For each campaign, I'd like to load in the CSVs, run some recodes, then merge them into one dataset for the whole campaign. Rather than copy the code hundreds of times then find and replace the numbers, I'm hoping there's a loop I can run that will just run through the code then do it again but with all the numbers increased by one.
Here's the first part of the script, for Campaign 23:

Campaign_23_Delivered <- read.csv("Campaign 23 - Delivered.csv")
Campaign_23_Opened <- read.csv("Campaign 23 - Opened.csv")
Campaign_23_Clicked <- read.csv("Campaign 23 - Clicked.csv")

Campaign_23_Delivered$Campaign_23_DateTime_Delivered <- mdy_hm(Campaign_23_Delivered$Date)
Campaign_23_Delivered$Campaign_23_Delivered <- 1
Campaign_23_Delivered <- Campaign_23_Delivered[c("Member.ID", "Campaign_23_Delivered", "Campaign_23_DateTime_Delivered")]

Campaign_23_Opened$Campaign_23_DateTime_Opened <- mdy_hm(Campaign_23_Opened$Date)
Campaign_23_Opened$Campaign_23_Opened <- 1
Campaign_23_Opened <- Campaign_23_Opened[c("Member.ID", "Campaign_23_Opened", "Campaign_23_DateTime_Opened")]

Campaign_23_Clicked$Campaign_23_DateTime_Clicked <- mdy_hm(Campaign_23_Clicked$Date)
Campaign_23_Clicked$Campaign_23_Clicked <- 1
Campaign_23_Clicked <- Campaign_23_Clicked[c("Member.ID", "Campaign_23_Clicked", "Campaign_23_DateTime_Clicked")]

Campaign_23 <- merge(Campaign_23_Delivered, Campaign_23_Opened, by = "Member.ID", all.x = TRUE)
Campaign_23 <- merge(Campaign_23, Campaign_23_Clicked, by = "Member.ID", all.x = TRUE)


I've found several questions and answers for loops, but none that allow me to adjust the number in the dataset AND in the column names like this. In other words, I'd like to run this whole set of code again, but with every instance of 23 replaced with 24, then 25, then 26, and so on.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've seen a few tutorials that walk through similar processes, like https://www.gerkelab.com/blog/2018/09/import-directory-csv-purrr-readr/ and https://www.mjandrews.org/blog/readmultifile/

I would suggest loading all the Delivered files in one go with purrr::map and read_csv, then all the Opened and Clicked files. Apply the transformations once loaded, then merge the three objects.

@Christopher, all your campaigns have these three csv? The're all in the same folder (or in their subfolders)?

@AdrianoMello, the large majority have all three CSVs. I would say fewer than 10 (so far) have only one or two. They are all in the same folder.

Generally for batch processing consider including your data in a list. Lists allow you to iterate over them using either a for loop or the apply family functions and easily apply whatever manipulation you need.
This approach assumes structure of top level directory with every campaign being in a separate sub-directory:
dir <- "/your/top/level/dir/here"
setwd(dir)
dirs <- list.dirs(full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)

out <- lapply(dirs, function(x){
  setwd(paste0(dir,"/",x))
  files <- list.files()
  fin <- lapply(files, function(y){
    temp <- read.csv(y)
    ###DO WHATEVER MANIPULATION YOU WANT TO DO ON THIS FILE HERE###
    })
  names(fin) <- files
  fin
})

In my case top level directory was test with three sub-directories named 1, 2 and 3 with 2 files (bla.csv and hey.csv) in the first one and 3 files (hi.csv, hey.csv and bla,csv in the other two). list.dirs and list.files functions just return a vector containing names of the directories/files in the working directory. We then iterate over these vectors with the lapply functions to enter each directory and read in all csv files as data frames.
Here is the output:
str(out)
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ bla.csv:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ heu.csv:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ bla.csv:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hey.csv:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hi.csv :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ bla.csv:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hey.csv:'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hi.csv :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4

out is a list which contains a list for each campaign/subdirectory which contains each of the datatframes. By iterating over this list you can easily do whatever edits you need in batch, and split/combine as needed.
If you have everything in the same directory consider something like this:
dir <- "/your/top/level/dir/here"
setwd(dir)
allfiles <- list.files()
out <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
  files <- allfiles[grep(as.character(i), allfiles)]
  fin <- lapply(files, function(x){
    temp <- read.csv(x)
    ###DO WHATEVER MANIPULATION YOU WANT TO DO ON THIS FILE HERE###
  })
  names(fin) <- files
  out <- append(out, list(fin), after = length(out))
}

This is essentially same idea, except you have to supply the number of iterations manually (in this example I have 3). We then use grep to pull out the filenames that share the same number. Here is the output:
str(out)
List of 3
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ bla1.csv:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hey1.csv:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ bla2.csv:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hey2.csv:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hi2.csv :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ bla3.csv:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hey3.csv:'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4
  ..$ hi3.csv :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ X  : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ foo: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ bar: int [1:3] 2 3 4


Here's my reproducible take (so others can try it).
Setup
# All you need (for now) --------------------------------------------------
# If you're looking for serious speed, maybe `data.table` is the answer
library(tidyverse)

# Setting the example -----------------------------------------------------

# Creating people
toy_data <- example_people <- tribble(
  ~member_id, ~email,                     ~first_name,  ~last_name,     ~activity,       ~date,
  1,           "john@email.com",          "John",       "Smith",        "Doctor",        "2023-01-01 10:30:00",
  2,           "mary@email.com",          "Mary",       "Johnson",      "Engineer",      "2023-01-02 11:45:00",
  3,           "peter@email.com",         "Peter",      "O'Connor",     "Professor",     "2023-01-03 09:15:00",
  4,           "anna@email.com",          "Anna",       "Brown",        "Lawyer",        "2023-01-04 14:20:00",
  5,           "charles@email.com",       "Charles",    "Davis",        "Artist",        "2023-01-05 13:10:00",
  6,           "sarah@email.com",         "Sarah",      "Robinson",     "Athlete",       "2023-01-06 08:45:00",
  7,           "richard@email.com",       "Richard",    "Martinez",     "Scientist",     "2023-01-07 12:00:00",
  8,           "laura@email.com",         "Laura",      "Lopez",        "Writer",        "2023-01-08 10:00:00",
  9,           "joseph@email.com",        "Joseph",     "Allen",        "Musician",      "2023-01-09 15:30:00",
  10,          "patricia@email.com",      "Patricia",   "Rivera",       "Designer",      "2023-01-10 16:40:00",
  11,          "andrew@email.com",        "Andrew",     "Peters",       "Politician",    "2023-01-11 07:55:00",
  12,          "claudia@email.com",       "Claudia",    "Cruz",         "Journalist",    "2023-01-12 11:20:00",
  13,          "anthony@email.com",       "Anthony",    "Gomez",        "Architect",     "2023-01-13 14:15:00",
  14,          "marianne@email.com",      "Marianne",   "Mendez",       "Chef",          "2023-01-14 09:35:00",
  15,          "roger@email.com",         "Roger",      "Evans",        "Photographer",  "2023-01-15 12:50:00",
  16,          "danielle@email.com",      "Danielle",   "Morris",       "Psychologist",  "2023-01-16 10:25:00",
  17,          "gustav@email.com",        "Gustav",     "Sanders",      "Engineer",      "2023-01-17 11:05:00",
  18,          "isabel@email.com",        "Isabel",     "Foster",       "Lawyer",        "2023-01-18 14:30:00",
  19,          "philip@email.com",        "Philip",     "Cook",         "Doctor",        "2023-01-19 08:15:00",
  20,          "christine@email.com",     "Christine",  "Barnes",       "Professor",     "2023-01-20 13:20:00",
  21,          "leonard@email.com",       "Leonard",    "Baker",        "Artist",        "2023-01-21 09:45:00",
  22,          "julie@email.com",         "Julie",      "Murray",       "Athlete",       "2023-01-22 15:00:00",
  23,          "brandon@email.com",       "Brandon",    "Rice",         "Scientist",     "2023-01-23 12:10:00",
  24,          "camilla@email.com",       "Camilla",    "Griffin",      "Writer",        "2023-01-24 08:55:00",
  25,          "sergio@email.com",        "Sergio",     "Diaz",         "Musician",      "2023-01-25 11:30:00",
  26,          "natalie@email.com",       "Natalie",    "Fisher",       "Designer",      "2023-01-26 14:45:00",
  27,          "edward@email.com",        "Edward",     "Wright",       "Politician",    "2023-01-27 09:20:00",
  28,          "anna@email.com",          "Anna",       "Nolan",        "Journalist",    "2023-01-28 12:35:00",
  29,          "louis@email.com",         "Louis",      "Moreno",       "Architect",     "2023-01-29 10:05:00",
  30,          "patricia@email.com",      "Patricia",   "Lima",         "Chef",          "2023-01-30 13:15:00")

# Creating five campaigns with three status each
toy_data <- bind_cols(
  toy_data, 
  expand.grid(a = paste0("campaign_", 1:5, "_"), 
              b = c("delivered", "opened", "clicked")) %>% 
    transmute(filename = paste0(a, b, ".csv")) %>% 
    slice_sample(by =filename, n = 2, replace = TRUE))

# Creating a folder
my_folder <- file.path(getwd(), "my_campaigns")
dir.create(my_folder)

# Creating the files
walk(
  unique(toy_data$filename),
  \(x) write_csv(
    x = select(filter(toy_data, filename == x), -filename), 
    file = file.path(my_folder, x)))

The folder should look like this:
> list.files(my_folder)
 [1] "campaign_1_clicked.csv"   "campaign_1_delivered.csv" "campaign_1_opened.csv"   
 [4] "campaign_2_clicked.csv"   "campaign_2_delivered.csv" "campaign_2_opened.csv"   
 [7] "campaign_3_clicked.csv"   "campaign_3_delivered.csv" "campaign_3_opened.csv"   
[10] "campaign_4_clicked.csv"   "campaign_4_delivered.csv" "campaign_4_opened.csv"   
[13] "campaign_5_clicked.csv"   "campaign_5_delivered.csv" "campaign_5_opened.csv" 

The code
Now let's read all these files and merge the campaigns into one r object each:
# The pipeline ------------------------------------------------------------

# Step 1: Find your files on your `my_folder` campaign folder..
aux <- list.files(my_folder, pattern = "campaign.*csv$", full.names = TRUE)

# ..and make a tibble out of it!
aux <- tibble(
  id         = 1:length(aux),
  filepath   = aux,
  cpn_name   = str_extract(basename(filepath), "^.*(?=_)"),
  cpn_id     = as.integer(str_extract(basename(filepath), "(?<=_)\\d+")),
  cpn_status = fct(
    str_extract(basename(filepath), "(?<=_)[:alpha:]+"),
    levels = c("delivered", "opened", "clicked")))

The aux table should look like this:
> aux %>% mutate(filepath = str_replace(filepath, "(?<=C.).*(?=.my)", " <--- Privacy!! ---> "))
# A tibble: 15 × 5
      id filepath                                                      cpn_name   cpn_id cpn_status
   <int> <chr>                                                         <chr>       <int> <fct>     
 1     1 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_1_clicked.csv   campaign_1      1 clicked   
 2     2 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_1_delivered.csv campaign_1      1 delivered 
 3     3 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_1_opened.csv    campaign_1      1 opened    
 4     4 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_2_clicked.csv   campaign_2      2 clicked   
 5     5 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_2_delivered.csv campaign_2      2 delivered 
 6     6 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_2_opened.csv    campaign_2      2 opened    
 7     7 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_3_clicked.csv   campaign_3      3 clicked   
 8     8 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_3_delivered.csv campaign_3      3 delivered 
 9     9 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_3_opened.csv    campaign_3      3 opened    
10    10 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_4_clicked.csv   campaign_4      4 clicked   
11    11 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_4_delivered.csv campaign_4      4 delivered 
12    12 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_4_opened.csv    campaign_4      4 opened    
13    13 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_5_clicked.csv   campaign_5      5 clicked   
14    14 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_5_delivered.csv campaign_5      5 delivered 
15    15 C: <--- Privacy!! ---> /my_campaigns/campaign_5_opened.csv    campaign_5      5 opened 

Reading and creating:
# Step 2: Read all campaigns and create their datasets!
walk2(
  unique(aux$cpn_id), unique(aux$cpn_name), # Iterate campaigns and obj names
  
  \(cpn_id, cpn_name) map_dfr( # Iterate the files from each campaign
      aux$id[aux$cpn_id == cpn_id],
      
      \(id) read_csv(aux$filepath[id], show_col_types = FALSE) %>% # Read them
        mutate(cpn_status = aux$cpn_status[id]) %>% # Create a status colum
        arrange(cpn_status, date)) %>%              # ..and sort by
    
    assign(envir = globalenv(), x = cpn_name))      # Make sure the objects
                                                    # exists outside the loop

The output
These are the r objects created:
> ls(pattern = "campaign")
[1] "campaign_1" "campaign_2" "campaign_3" "campaign_4" "campaign_5"

And this is how they should look like:
> mget(ls(pattern = "campaign"))
$campaign_1
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  member_id email             first_name last_name activity   date                cpn_status
      <dbl> <chr>             <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <dttm>              <fct>     
1        21 leonard@email.com Leonard    Baker     Artist     2023-01-21 09:45:00 clicked   
2        22 julie@email.com   Julie      Murray    Athlete    2023-01-22 15:00:00 clicked   
3         1 john@email.com    John       Smith     Doctor     2023-01-01 10:30:00 delivered 
4         2 mary@email.com    Mary       Johnson   Engineer   2023-01-02 11:45:00 delivered 
5        11 andrew@email.com  Andrew     Peters    Politician 2023-01-11 07:55:00 opened    
6        12 claudia@email.com Claudia    Cruz      Journalist 2023-01-12 11:20:00 opened    

$campaign_2
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  member_id email              first_name last_name activity  date                cpn_status
      <dbl> <chr>              <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <dttm>              <fct>     
1        23 brandon@email.com  Brandon    Rice      Scientist 2023-01-23 12:10:00 clicked   
2        24 camilla@email.com  Camilla    Griffin   Writer    2023-01-24 08:55:00 clicked   
3         3 peter@email.com    Peter      O'Connor  Professor 2023-01-03 09:15:00 delivered 
4         4 anna@email.com     Anna       Brown     Lawyer    2023-01-04 14:20:00 delivered 
5        13 anthony@email.com  Anthony    Gomez     Architect 2023-01-13 14:15:00 opened    
6        14 marianne@email.com Marianne   Mendez    Chef      2023-01-14 09:35:00 opened    

$campaign_3
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  member_id email              first_name last_name activity     date                cpn_status
      <dbl> <chr>              <chr>      <chr>     <chr>        <dttm>              <fct>     
1        25 sergio@email.com   Sergio     Diaz      Musician     2023-01-25 11:30:00 clicked   
2        26 natalie@email.com  Natalie    Fisher    Designer     2023-01-26 14:45:00 clicked   
3         5 charles@email.com  Charles    Davis     Artist       2023-01-05 13:10:00 delivered 
4         6 sarah@email.com    Sarah      Robinson  Athlete      2023-01-06 08:45:00 delivered 
5        15 roger@email.com    Roger      Evans     Photographer 2023-01-15 12:50:00 opened    
6        16 danielle@email.com Danielle   Morris    Psychologist 2023-01-16 10:25:00 opened    

$campaign_4
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  member_id email             first_name last_name activity   date                cpn_status
      <dbl> <chr>             <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <dttm>              <fct>     
1        27 edward@email.com  Edward     Wright    Politician 2023-01-27 09:20:00 clicked   
2        28 anna@email.com    Anna       Nolan     Journalist 2023-01-28 12:35:00 clicked   
3         7 richard@email.com Richard    Martinez  Scientist  2023-01-07 12:00:00 delivered 
4         8 laura@email.com   Laura      Lopez     Writer     2023-01-08 10:00:00 delivered 
5        17 gustav@email.com  Gustav     Sanders   Engineer   2023-01-17 11:05:00 opened    
6        18 isabel@email.com  Isabel     Foster    Lawyer     2023-01-18 14:30:00 opened    

$campaign_5
# A tibble: 6 × 7
  member_id email               first_name last_name activity  date                cpn_status
      <dbl> <chr>               <chr>      <chr>     <chr>     <dttm>              <fct>     
1        29 louis@email.com     Louis      Moreno    Architect 2023-01-29 10:05:00 clicked   
2        30 patricia@email.com  Patricia   Lima      Chef      2023-01-30 13:15:00 clicked   
3         9 joseph@email.com    Joseph     Allen     Musician  2023-01-09 15:30:00 delivered 
4        10 patricia@email.com  Patricia   Rivera    Designer  2023-01-10 16:40:00 delivered 
5        19 philip@email.com    Philip     Cook      Doctor    2023-01-19 08:15:00 opened    
6        20 christine@email.com Christine  Barnes    Professor 2023-01-20 13:20:00 opened  

That's pretty much it!
Created on 2024-05-09 with reprex v2.1.0

Reading your CSV files into a list of data frames and using a function like lapply() to process them is one approach.
This code assumes you have the 3 files in the same format for all campaigns, and that all the files are saved in your current working directory.
There are 2 functions defined here:

one to do the processing on each data.frame, i.e. format the date and set the relevant flag. This gets run on each data frame in the list.
another to combine the 3 data frames corresponding to each number

filenames <- list.files(pattern = "^Campaign")

all_data <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
names(all_data) <- filenames

modify_data <- function(name) {
    dt_varname <- gsub("Campaign_(\\d+)_(\\w+)", "Campaign_\\1_Datetime_\\2", name)
    result <- all_data[[name]]
    result[[dt_varname]] <- lubridate::mdy_hm(result[["Date"]])
    result[[name]] <- 1
    result <- result[c("Member.ID", name, dt_varname)]
    return(result)
}

all_data <- lapply(names(all_data), modify_data)
names(all_data) <- filenames

combine_data <- function(number) {

    delivered_name <- sprintf("Campaign_%s_Delivered", number)
    opened_name <- sprintf("Campaign_%s_Opened", number)
    clicked_name <- sprintf("Campaign_%s_Clicked", number)

    result <- merge(
                    all_data[[delivered_name]],
                    all_data[[opened_name]],
                    by = "Member.ID", all.x = TRUE
    )
    result <- merge(
                    result,
                    all_data[[sprintf("Campaign_%s_Clicked", number)]],
                    by = "Member.ID", all.x = TRUE
    )
    return(result)
}

numbers <- unique(gsub("^\\w+_(\\d+)_.*$", "\\1", filenames))
final_data <- lapply(numbers, combine_data)
names(final_data) <- paste0("Campaign_", numbers)


